# The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)') || SqlAlchemy, Sql Azure

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

DB version : Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Oct 12 2019 22:46:48 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

I have a sqlalchemy-orm model `Process` as given below.

```
class Process(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Process'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    process = Column(UnicodeText)
    process_length = Column(Integer)
```

I am trying to run the following query to find any row where process matches the string `sorted_json`.

```
current_process = session.query(Process).filter(Process.process==sorted_json).one_or_none()
```

This query runs into an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I have tried changing the datatype of the column `process` to `ntext` in the backend. When I run the query it gives a bizarre error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types ntext and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

It should be noted that `sorted_json` is a **very long json string** with around 4000 characters. I believe sqlalchemy is casting this string to ntext while querying.

I have instead tried the like function of sqlalchemy like:

```
current_process = session.query(Process).filter(Process.process.like(sorted_json)).one_or_none()
```

No errors here but it is not providing a match when there is an actual match.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't change the data type to `ntext` in SQL Server, the data type has been deprecated for 14 years and should be avoided. It has less functionality than an `nvarchar(MAX)` and will be removed in a future version; meaning your code won't work any more.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/620 - Apparently, by default, the ODBC driver sends long string parameter values as `ntext` instead of `nvarchar(max)`, possibly for legacy reasons.

Comment: @Larnu The datatype was changed by sqlalchemy or the pyodbc driver. Anyway the issue was solved by casting the `sorted_json` to `NVARCHAR` in the orm query. Thanks.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks. That was the issue.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth - Good to hear that you got it sorted out. Please consider posting your findings as an answer so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved partially by casting `sorted_json` string to `NVARCHAR` within the orm query like:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, NVARCHAR
session.query(Process).filter(Process.process==cast(sorted_json,NVARCHAR)).one_or_none()
```

As @GordThomson mentioned, the issue is at the odbc driver end. The issue is mentioned here: [github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/620](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/620)